# Redirect doesn't work properly

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, header, authorization

My signin procedure looks like that:

- User fills email and pass fields
- Ajax sends these fields to `reg_system.php`. Here is source code of
  file

.

```
if (isset($_POST['formID']) && !empty($_POST['formID'])) {
    $registration = new registration($db);
    $forms = array('signup_form', 'signin_form', 'tcr_form');
    if (in_array($_POST['formID'], $forms)) {
        $redirect = "";
        switch ($_POST['formID']) {
            case 'signin_form':
                if ($registration->signin())
                    $redirect ='me';
                break;
            case 'tcr_form':
            case 'signup_form':
                $registration->signup();
                break;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($redirect))
         header("Location:".wsurl."?page=".$redirect); 
}
```

*Note*: wsurl declared before, and is right value.

- If `$registration->signin()` returns true it must redirect to
     `domain.com/?page=me`

During debug process, I see that all goes well and $registration->signin() function returns true.But right after post process Firebug XHR shows this screen

[image]

Then after redirection
[image]

Page stays as it is: on the same login page. Script doesn't redirect to anywhere..

I don't know what can cause this, because checked whole debug process nearly 10x time. PHP doesn't output anything before header().

Comment: Why would you want to redirect an ajax request? If you want to redirect user after sumbission, you should not use ajax, but a simple form instead, OR, redirect user with javascript, like this `location.href = '...'` after successful ajax request.

Comment: But, does it load when you type in the url manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JS for your redirections. It might be better than doing it through php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = <?php echo wsurl."?page=".$redirect; ?>;
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: _It's always better than doing it through php._ `[citation needed]`

Comment: @Michael I can't find evidence to back up my theory, I guess I'll edit my answer! :)

Comment: Try this with javascript turned *off* ;) - Joke aside, I think the AJAX success handler should deal with it.

Comment: Meh, pretty much everyone everywhere is moving to more and more client side programming rather than server side. I don't think anyone cares about the nubs who have js disabled.